# Four vertices of a regular dodecagon are randomly selected. Find the probability that they form a rectangle (including squares).

Tags: probability, geometry

Four points are randomly selected from the set of the vertices of a regular  dodecagon (or 12 sided regular polygon). Find the probability that those four points  form a rectangle (including squares).

I tried by trying to see the cases where there are rectangles or squares by connecting some vertices, but ended up resorting to bashing. It would be helpful if someone gives a less bashy way to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us how you got started and where  you are stuck. Perhaps try the problem first for an octabon.

Comment: Hint. Once one point in a rectangle has been chosen the second determines the other two. Then just take care that you don't count each rectangle four times.

Comment: Thank you, I get it know!

Comment: When you're done, answer your own question here and accept your answer, so folks know not to pay more attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

If a rectangle is inscribed in a regular dodecagon, each diagonal of the rectangle joins two diametrically opposite vertices of the dodecagon. There are $6$ lines joining opposite vertices of the dodecagon, and for each such line there are $5$ rectangles with that line as a diagonal, and $6\times 5=30$. But this counts each rectangle twice (since it has two diagonals), so the actual number of rectangles is $30/2=15$, and the desired probability is
$$\frac{15}{\binom{12}4}=\frac{15}{495}=\frac1{33}.$$